# Canon EDSDK Device Busy when changing property

Tags: edsdk

I have a little problem with EDSDK.
I tried to make a function that can switch from **liveview** to **movie record**.

Everything is fine with liveview, I can take picture.
But when I want to start movie record, I have a `ERR_DEVICE_BUSY` everytime I want to change a property (save to camera instead of PC). I try everything, make a loop, nothing. And it's the only place where I get this error.

Here's my code :

```
    EdsDataType dataType;


    EdsUInt32 dataSize;
    EdsUInt32 enregistrement;
    err = EdsGetPropertySize(camera, kEdsPropID_SaveTo, 0, &dataType, &dataSize);

    err = EdsGetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_SaveTo, 0, dataSize, &enregistrement);
    EdsUInt32 saveTo = kEdsSaveTo_Camera;
    if(enregistrement != kEdsSaveTo_Camera){
        err = EdsSetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_SaveTo, 0, sizeof(saveTo), &saveTo);
        if(err != EDS_ERR_OK){
            printf("Erreur de changement d'emplacement de sauvegarde, arret de l'enregistrement\n");
            printf("err : 0x%X\n", err);
            return err;
        }
    }

    //Changement du mode de prise de vu
    EdsUInt32 mode = 20; //Le monde 20 correspont à l'enregistrement vidéo
    EdsSetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_AEMode, 0, sizeof(mode), &mode);

    //Variable pour la mise en route et l'arrêt de l'enregistrement
    EdsUInt32 debutEnregistrement = 4;
    EdsUInt32 finEnregistrement = 0;


    err = EdsSetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_Record, 0, sizeof(debutEnregistrement), &debutEnregistrement);
    if(err != EDS_ERR_OK){
        printf("Erreur lors du lancement de l'enregistrement");
        return err;
    }
        //Wait for stop record
err = EdsSetPropertyData(camera, kEdsPropID_Record, 0, sizeof(finEnregistrement), &finEnregistrement);
    if(err != EDS_ERR_OK)
        printf("Erreur lors de l'arret de l'enregistrement");

    //L'enregistrement est fini, vérification des evenement
    EdsGetEvent();
```

If you have solution, I take, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what the docs say, the EDSDK sometimes returns EDS_ERR_DEVICE_BUSY for EdsSetPropertyData() when the actual error is a bad input parameter.  For example, try setting kEdsPropID_Av with a value of decimal 50 (0x32) which is not in the table given in the documentation.  On my EOS 5Ds, this returns EDS_ERR_DEVICE_BUSY no matter how many retries are attempted.  Passing a legal value, e.g. 0x33 (for f/6.3) succeeds first time.  The bug is 100% reproducible here.

So, if you get this "device busy" error when setting properties, check the input values you are passing with a fine-toothed comb.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this I don't know if you already but it should work it has for me so far on all my property changes.

- Just after you opened the session use the `EdsSetPropertyEventHandler` function
- Begin by stopping you LiveView by putting `kEdsEvfOutputDevice` at `TFT` if  I recall good. (the parameter that is not PC).
- In the call back of the property event handler you make a switch on the event and when it is for the property kEdsEvfOutputDevice, then you throw your function to go to movie mode.

the callback function will be called when the property changed will be made so you won't have any device busy or notready. But becareful you have to set your callback function to static so that it works. So you wont be able to call anyother functions that the one that are static, the same for the variables.

If you didn't understand I can explain it to you in french, far more easy for me ^^